# Is it possible to get a regex that select the table flip characters?

Tags: jquery, regex

I'm looking to select the Table flip characters using regex

```
(╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻
```

^ this guy

so far the regex I have come up with was

```
(?i)\b(╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻\b
```

But it doesn't work. Any guidance would be appreciated.

-J

Comment: Remove `\b` from the pattern. Escape ASCII `)` and `(`

Comment: Also there's really no need for a regexp if you have no dynamic part. A plain-text search (and replace?) would be as effective and more efficient

Comment: @Aaron I'm using a pre-existing bot that uses regex, otherwise I would just do it that way.

Comment: @JayLarson ok, that stands to reason. I think you should however remove the `(?i)` flag, either those characters have no case or you don't want to match the other case

Answer (score 1):

This is really just Wiktor Stribiżew's comment, in answer form, with example code:

```
var flipper = '(╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻';
var pattern = /\(╯°□°\）╯︵ ┻━┻/;

window.alert(pattern.test(flipper));
```

The word boundaries (`\b`) caused your regex to fail because the flipper includes characters that are not word (`A-Za-z0-9_`) characters.

Comment: I don't think OP has agreed it  works. I do not think you need to escape the full-width closing bracket, it does not have any special meaning in regex.